# iphonesdk button+table issue

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

[image: screenshot]

This is the screen shot.  Faraz is coming from address book contact name. When I click on template button I switch to that Arabic part(next page). What I wanted is to add faraz + selected template into mutable array. How can i make this happen so my selected template will be added with selected contact name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using NSDictionary.... make ur key as "faraz" and for that key, the value should be "selected template"

```
NSMutableDictionary *myDictionary = [[ NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[ myDictionary setObject:@"selected template" forKey:@"faraz"];
```